# Would this Conjure Dragons spell be too powerful?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, homebrew-review

Would this homebrewed spell for dragon-themed conjurers be too powerful? It is a variant of *conjure animals* / *conjure minor elementals* / *conjure woodland beings* but dragon-themed.

This is what I have so far:

> Level 3 conjuration spell (for wizard conjurers or sorcerers with draconic bloodline)
>
> - 1 × CR 2 (e.g. a dragon wyrmling or fairy dragon)
> - 2 × CR 1 (e.g. dragon wyrmlings or some fairy dragons)
> - 4 × CR ½ (???)
> - 8 × CR ¼ (e.g. pseudodragons)

I figure that, if I was to compare a dragon wyrmling to a polar bear, the dragon has more AC (17), 1 attack at +6 (+2 damage), and breath weapon once every 6 turns, while the polar bear has less AC (12), 2 attacks at +7 (+5 damage each), but both are otherwise CR 2 and have about the same number of hit points.

Answer (score 16):

Your proposed *Conjure Dragons* spell should probably be a 4th level spell rather than a 3rd level. Other than that, it looks fine.

My reasoning is simple: There are 2 spells, *Conjure Animals*, and *Conjure Woodland Beings*, that are identical in every respect, except that *Conjure Animals* summons creatures with the beast type, and *Conjure Woodland Beings* summons creatures with the fey type. While *Conjure Animals* is a 3rd level spell, *Conjure Woodland Beings* is a 4th level spell. This is because fey have a wide variety of special abilities, while beasts have none. For example, a Pixie is CR 1/4, but it has a whole bunch of different spells it can cast. Obviously, there aren't any beasts with similar powers.  *Conjure Fey* therefore has a great deal more versatility and utility than *Conjure Animals*, so it is 1 spell level higher.

The same principle holds with your *Conjure Dragons* spell; it is identical to *Conjure Animals*, except that dragons have a wide variety of special abilities. Wyrmlings all have breath weapons, and the Faerie Dragon has spellcasting. Therefore, *Conjure Dragons* would be a much more versatile, and therefore powerful, spell than *Conjure Animals*. It doesn't appear significantly more powerful than *Conjure Woodland Beings*, though, so I'd suggest that making it a 4th level spell should be about right.

Answer (score -8):

I think that this would be way too powerful for a level 3 spell.  Maybe level 9, but only after very careful consideration.  I might approve it if the dragon summoned was opposie in alignment on a fumble.  Imagine you wizard deciding to get a bit of help tries to summon a metallic dragon and ends up summoning a Red.

Comment: I think lvl 9 might be overrated, wyrmling are only cr2 (red blue and gold are not in the choices since they are cr4-3-3) plus the spell is a concentration base spell with a duration of 1H. The wizard wont be able to use an other concentration spell while his wyrmling is on stage. Plus he risck to lose concentration if attacked, wich would lead to the lost of the wyrmling.

Comment: Maybe level 9 is making it overpowered, but it should be.

Comment: A lvl 5 druid can summon a cr 2 beast (polar bear) and a lvl 11 druid can summon a cr 6 fey... Way more powerful then a little dragon wyrmling. Those 2 spells are lvl 3 and lvl 6 spells. Plus the alignment dont count, the wyrmling is not a real beast, it's a spirit whitch look like a wyrmling, it is friendly to the caster and his team and will never act on his own. It follows the orders of the caster and will only defend itself (not move) if no orders are givin. Actually the only things that bothers me about the wyrmling is there AR 16 and 17 is high.

Comment: @CharlieHorse this is in no way 'overpowered' as a 9th level spell.  Other 9th level spells include *Wish*.  A wyrmling is not a *Wish*, nor even reasonably on the same level as one, let alone 'overpowered' compared to it.  Also summons are controlled so getting a Red Dragon, rather than a Gold one, wouldn't actually matter at all.  Of course as a 9th level spell that incapacitates the caster, both are effectively suicide, but that's a different problem.